# Manipulating docm files with Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-docx

I was looking how to manipulate docm files with Python and found this library named `python-docx-docm`.

I followed the documentation and tried a simple programm :

```
import docx

doc = docx.Document(my docm file)

all_paras = doc.paragraphs

for para in all_paras:
    print(para.text)
    print("-----------")
```

To which I am geting the following error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\clemdcz\Desktop\Projet\intoWORD.py", line 3, in <module>
    doc = docx.Document(r'C:\Users\clemdcz\Desktop\my_file.docm')
  File "C:\Users\clemdcz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\docx\api.py", line 36, in Document
    return document_part.document
AttributeError: 'Part' object has no attribute 'document'
```

If I then try with a docx file it works fine and shows me the correct data. So I was wondering on how to fix this error ?

The documentation doesn't seem to give informations on docm file. But I read that it was supposed to work the same for both docm and docx. I couldn't find any other libraries that could manipulate docx files with python.

Comment: The code will definitely work with docm files. Did you install the module 'python-docx-docm'? Also you should paste the *complete* traceback in your question and **format it as code** to help determine issues.

Comment: Yes I did indeed install the module 'python-docx-docm'. I updated my question with the full traceback.

Comment: Interesting. As you can see from the trace back the line **doc = docx.Document(my docm file)** creates the Document object and returns the  'document' attribute, **return document_part.document**. This is in my module which definitely creates the object with that attribute whether its a .docx or .docm file. This doesn't seem to happen with for your .docm file however does for .docx files. My module version is 0.1.0 and I cannot find any listed issue regarding this type of error for the module.

Comment: Without the docm file its hard to make any further determination on why it doesn't work however I certainly suggest that you try other docm file(s) if you haven't already.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the "python-docx-docm" forks (because this MR was never merged: https://github.com/python-openxml/python-docx/pull/716 ) has an error and you get the error you mentionned when you try to open a docm file:

```
AttributeError: 'Part' object has no attribute 'document'
```

It can be monkey patched on-the-fly in the code, with this line of code:

```
docx.opc.part.PartFactory.part_type_for[docx.opc.constants.CONTENT_TYPE.WML_DOCUMENT_MACRO_ENABLED_MAIN] = docx.parts.document.DocumentPart
```

With this modification, docm file can be opened with the "python-docx-docm" fork